# Show that for all $k,l\in \mathbb Z, f(k+l)=f(k)+f(l)+kl$, that $f(0)=0$ and that for all $k\in \mathbb Z\,, f(-k)=k^2-f(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\text{Let }\quad f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \quad \text{ and }\quad  M_f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R^{3,3}, \quad k\mapsto  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & k & f(k) \\
0 & 1 & k  \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
.$$
Further let $U:=\operatorname{image}(M_f)$. The function $f$ is chosen such that for all $A,B \in U$ $AB\in U$.

> Show that for all $k,l\in \mathbb Z, f(k+l)=f(k)+f(l)+kl$, that $f(0)=0$ and that for all $k\in \mathbb Z\,, f(-k)=k^2-f(k)$.

I do not see how to start here? I am clueless and do not understand what I have to do here.  Some approaches are welcome!

Comment: Let $A=M_f(k)$ and $B=M_f(l).$ By hypothesis, one knows that $AB=M_f(t)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Compute $AB.$ Since it is $M_f(t),$ it has a particular form. With that you can find what $t$ should be (check the entry in the first row and second column, or the entry in the third column and second row). With that, you'all find what $f(t)$ is. This proves the first statement, notice that the second follows from the first.

Comment: yes thanks to this the first two parts are clear!

Comment: the third is clear too. Thanks, Diego.